# Mysqld service suddelny down, Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

Somebody please help, 
mysqld just crash recently. How to troubleshoot this issue?
It's my first-time to encounter this problem.

After a couple of minutes
[screenshot_mysqld_service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8sPS.png)

I rechecked for mysqld status

```
sudo systemctl status mysqld
```

[status_mysqld_service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCCfR.png)

And I just checked for syslog and this is what I got

```
May 23 00:15:38 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:15:38 0 [ERROR] Aborting
May 23 00:15:38 www mysqld:
May 23 00:15:38 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:15:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
May 23 00:15:39 www mysqld: Warning: Memory not freed: 520
May 23 00:15:39 www mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/www.example.com.pid ended
May 23 00:17:30 www mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
May 23 00:17:30 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:17:30 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.23-MariaDB-1:10.3.23+maria~xenial) starting as process 5554 ...
May 23 00:17:30 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:17:30 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
May 23 00:18:01 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.23 started; log sequence number 795310001; transaction id 728172
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld: 2020-05-23  0:18:02 0 [ERROR] Aborting
May 23 00:18:02 www mysqld:
May 23 00:18:03 www mysqld: Warning: Memory not freed: 520
May 23 00:18:03 www mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/www.example.com.pid ended
```

Thanks

Comment: Undo the changes you've made to /etc/mysql/my.cnf and try again with `sudo mysqld_safe`

Comment: nothing happended dude @Dougie. I run the command and it gave me the output 200523 00:17:30 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
200523 00:17:30 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

Comment: So look in /var/log/syslog to see what's going wrong.

Comment: oke, I just edited my question @Dougie

Comment: You've got two instances of mysqld running.